# How to serve several Web Socket

Tags: django, websocket

I have 30 smart-sensors distributed in several private networks with Internet access (all of them). I have to establish a persistent connection (socket) between those sensors and a server which has a public IP.

A user can access each sensor through a website (Django) and send or get data.

From your point of view, how can I ensure several persistent and private connections? I found https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-websocket, but I think is not suitable for my application because I cannot recover an existent socket connection from other Django views.

### Any suggestions are very well received.

I found a good approach using Twisted Perspective Broker with JSON-RPC in the server providing methods to support each smart sensor, and for the other side each sensor will use a JSON library to authenticate (basic) and send data.

What do you think? Is this a good solution? I will post results as soon as I test it.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a seperate server that keeps the persistent connections, and allow the django application to query it. Twisted can provide a great framework for writing simple, single purpouse servers, and there is a good tutorial on how to write an XML-RPC server [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/web/howto/xmlrpc.html). Python has excellent support for XML-RPC, and it should be easy enough to get it up and running.

Comment: This is quite useful but not for this porpuse, beacse xmlrpm only can execute remote methods from a client which is executing a linux box, python and the twisted module, and in this case, each smart meters can only request URL or open a simple socket. The difficult that I identified is to have a list of listeners already connected to the server and process the information that is flowing from each socket to server and associate it to a known entity in a django server and save the new incoming data.

Comment: Moreover I was readung that Twisted is single threaded and of course this could cause blocking on the entire server if several sensors are posting data to the server at the same time

Comment: Or you could use a separate thread to control the data, and use the main thread to run the Twisted server. Multithreading with twisted is much easier than with a complex framework like django. Or alternatively, you could just run your sockets non blocking...

Comment: I will study twisted, it seems could be useful if I implement a JSON-RPC server, this way I could construct json/javascript mime request from each smart sensor and process the data in a suitable way using some methods in the server (twisted based). But I am still looking for a scalable way to send data (like a private message) from server to a smart-meter (sockets handling ?)

Comment: Node.js is also worth considering.